Maintaining a Python function docstring via a separate Python script
My goal is to make a repeatable Python function doc string maintenance process that can be executed to update parameter options when they change as a function is developed. This would remove the need to manually update the doc string for it to accurately reflect parameter options.
I would like to write functions in python script one which use parameters that are variables defined as an Enum class in another script two and imported for use in script one functions. Then in script three access the doc string of a function in script one and update it to reflect the parameter variables used from script two.
Please provide examples on how to achieve the code comment in three.py.
Edit (@Friedrich): Expected result is an edit to the doc text in the source file for do_something() in one.py.
Also if there are other methods of achieving this already available please make me aware.
Thanks!
example:
one.py
from two import * 

def do_something(add_one = DoSomethingParams.add_one.value[0], number = 0):
   """doc string to update"""
   if add_one:
      return number + 1

two.py
from aenum import Enum

class DoSomethingParams(Enum):
    add_one = ['default', 'option2', 'option3']

three.py
from one import * 
from two import * 

doc_to_update = do_something.__doc__

parameter_options_to_insert = DoSomethingParams.__members__

#code required to edit one.py do_something() doc string


I've worked on editing the .py file text by detecting the correct starting position of the function doc in the text file string, but this seems like a pretty basic code heavy way of doing it.

Could you [edit] and show your expected result? Do you want to modify the source files or is this about injecting something into the __doc__ properties?

@Friedrich thanks for the question. Edit source files. Post updated
